# Im unsure of why my http server is not reading in a filelocation C++

Tags: c++, http, file-io

Im creating a http server in c++.  I know that TCPServer.h works and that thing/text.txt exists but for some reason the code doesnt read the text file when I do 127.0.0.1.  If you would like TCPServer.h to help help just ask I would be more than happy to send it but I just didnt see a reason to do it

```
#include "TCPServer.h"
#include <future>
#include <fstream>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>
#include <iostream>
#define MAX_BUF (4096)
#pragma comment (lib, "ws2_32.lib")
char * getLoc(char * c) {
    char * ret = (char *)malloc(4096);
    ZeroMemory(ret, 4096);
    for(int i = 4; i < 4092; i++) {
        if (*(c + i) == ' ') {
            return ret;
        }
    else {
        *(ret + i - 4) = *(c + i);
    }
}
return ret;
}
void doStuff(SOCKET sock) {
        char * recieved = (char *)malloc(4096);
    recv(sock, recieved, 4096, 0);
    char * loc = getLoc(recieved);
    std::string fileLocation("thing");
    fileLocation += loc;
    std::ifstream fil;
    fil.open(fileLocation);
    char * contents = (char *)malloc(4096);
    ZeroMemory(contents, 4096);
    fil.read(contents, 4096);
    fil.close();
    std::cout << fileLocation;
    std::string shoot("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n");
    shoot += contents;
    std::cout << "\n\n\n" << shoot;
    send(sock, shoot.c_str(), 4096, 0);
}
int main() {
TCPServ s;
s.createSock(80);
while (true) {
    SOCKET sock = s.listenFor();
    std::future <void> f = std::async(doStuff, sock);
}
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *doesn't read the text file*? What is in the text file? Are you sure it opens the file successfully?

Comment: Im not sure tbh.... Im really confused as to whats going on.  The path is correct I checked that but than it doesnt get any output from it.

Comment: Well check if it fails when it tries to open, if not, then that's not the issue. Then it might be relevant what is inside the file, if the file (for any reason) starts with `\0` then you won't see anything, because `shoot += contents;` won't append anything to your string.

Comment: alright thank you, it failed so I guess thats what I need to work on.... Im really confused because the path looks right.  Im just making sure but C++ uses forward slashes for file paths right?

Comment: @ICantThinkOfAUsername C++ has no opinion on what kind of slashes you should use, use whatever works for your OS

Comment: I believe you need to do some reading about both HTTP and TCP/IP. TCP is a streaming protocol; you can't assume that you receive everything in a `recv` that was sent in a `send`. And the HTTP newline designator is `"\r\n"`.

Comment: My crystal ball suspects that your working directory is not the directory where 'thing' is. Don't use relative paths.

Comment: And mind your language when you share code, please.

Comment: Alright Ill try without the working directory

Comment: Oh Im sorry I forgot I named my function that, I was kinda tired Im sorry

Comment: it seems to be working now thanks guys.  Sorry about the function name